# Can I prevent implicit casts to parameters when calling a method?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, unsafe

I'm trying to clean up some code I've inherited, and I'm wondering if there's a way in C# to prevent implicit casts of method parameters.  We have a series of overloaded methods that take a variety of parameters, but we get unexpected/bad results if an incoming parameter is cast to a different type than what the method is using (hence the overloads).

For example, this

```
private unsafe void MyMethod(float arg0, float arg1)
{
  /* Do Very Unsafe Things */
}
```

will get called by this

```
int i = 0;
int j = 1;
MyMethod(i, j);
```

if I don't have a specific overload to take `(int, int)`.

I want to find some way at compile time to ensure that we have to write the `(int, int)` version of the method to call it like that instead of having the compiler "help" by using implicit casting.  Is this possible?

Comment: Don't know about any built-in tool, but Roslyn analyzer or diagnoster would make it possible.

Comment: That's a good point. Maybe I should look at setting up a check-in policy or some other tool to help prevent us from checking in without explicitly writing the versions of `MyMethod` we need.

Comment: You could try creating a class in place of the float and defining the implicit cast for each type. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx